# Suma de dos cubos de ramanujan

Tags: algoritmos, haskell

estoy teniendo problemas con resolver un ejercicio sobre la suma de cubos de ramanujan. No se me cae una idea de como poder empezar a resolver siquiera el problema. Quise hacer una recursion para probar si los numeros que pasaban por la funcion eran cubos y, si al sumarlos me daban como resultado "n", que me marcara como True la suma de dos cubos, y de lo contrario que siguiera intentando con otros numeros, pero ahi es donde me quedo atascado y nose como seguir.

```
esUnCubo:: Integer -> Bool

esUnCubo x = (round (fromIntegral x ** (1/3))) ^ 3 == x


esSumaDeDosCubos :: Integer -> Bool

esSumaDeDosCubos n | esUnCubo a + esUnCubo b == True
                   | otherwise = False
                   where a  = 1 + 0
```

adjunto la consigna.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: "Intenté de todo" es posiblemente la frase menos descriptiva en una pregunta de programación. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: En lugar de probar si diferentes sumandos son o no cubos, veo más futuro a ir probando enteros menores que n, elevarlos al cubo, sumarlos, y ver si sale n. Tendrías que probar todos los enteros desde 1 hasta raiz cúbica de n + 1, y para cada uno de ellos el otro "factor" iría desde i hasta n-1. Tendría por tanto complejidad O(n^(2/3)). Hay algoritmos más eficientes (menor complejidad computacional) pero menos directos, basados en propiedades del módulo 9 y módulo 7 de un cubo. Por desgracia no sé haskell, pero si te sirve puedo darte una respuesta en pseudocódigo, o en Python.

Comment: Hola, si me podria serivir, Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de abordar el problema. Una solución rápida es obtener todas las sumas de cubos y comprobar si coincide con el número que queremos chequear.

La lista de sumas de cubos:

```hs
listaSumaCubos :: Integer -> [Integer]
listaSumaCubos n = [ a^3 + b^3 | a <- [1..n], b <- [1..n]]
```

Ya sólo queda comprobar:

```hs
esSumaDeDosCubos :: Integer -> Bool
esSumaDeDosCubos n = elem n $ listaSumaCubos n
```

Una vez conseguida una solución, puedes empezar a pensar en optimizarla.

Comment: no habia pensado abordarlo de esa forma, lo implementare asi, gracias!!

Comment: Ten en cuenta que se puede optimizar mucho más. Por ejemplo, puedes añadir la restricción `a <= b` para quitar repetidos en `listaSumaCubos`.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta que dio ChemaCortes es valida sin embargo tiene una complejidad de `O(n^2)`, es decir que con números mayores a `10^4` va a comenzar a tardar demasiado tu algoritmo. Si quieres algo mas óptimo, puedes iterar por todos los números hasta `N` y luego con tu función `esUnCubo` validar si `N - i^3` es un cubo, esto tendría una complejidad de `O(N)` y te correría sin problemas con números de `10^6`

Te quedaría algo como esto

```
listaSumaCubos :: Integer -> [Bool]
listaSumaCubos n = [ esUnCubo (n - i^3) | i <- [1..n]]
```

Te comparto mi canal de YouTube donde explico diferentes ejercicios de algoritmia de este tipo por si te interesa https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCi73_SMLFY7xhvNGCLbsseQ